# Calculator Sample in iOS: The = sign is not responding to my code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to learn iOS and I was following the Standford University Videos, I was trying to recreate a Calculator sample. But for some reason the = button is not working or not giving the results. I have follow the exercise step by step but is not working for me at all. Can anyone help me with this, I will really appreciate it.

//This is my Calculator.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    CalculatorBrain *brain;
    BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber;
}
-(IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *) sender;
-(IBAction) operationPressed: (UIButton *) sender;


@end
<code>





//This is my Calculator.m 

<pre>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"


@implementation ViewController

-(CalculatorBrain *) brain
    {
    if (!brain) brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];

        return brain;
     }
-(IBAction) digitPressed:(UIButton *) sender
    {
    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel]text];

    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber)
    {
        [display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit]];

    }else{

        [display setText:digit];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;


    }
}

-(IBAction) operationPressed: (UIButton *) sender
  {

    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber)
  {
        [[self brain] setOperand:[[display text] doubleValue]];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;

  }
    NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    double result = [[self brain] performOperation:operation];
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result]];
  }

@end
<code>





//This is my CalculatorBrain.h

<pre>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject {

    double operand;
    NSString *waitingOperation;
    double waitingOperand;


}
-(void)setOperand:(double)anOperand;
-(double)performOperation:(NSString *) operation;

@end
<code>





//This is my CalculatorBrain.m
<pre>
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@implementation CalculatorBrain

-(void)setOperand:(double)anOperand{

    operand = anOperand;

}
-(void) performWaitingOperation{

    if ([@"+" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand + operand;
    }
    else if ([@"*" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand - operand;
    }
    else if ([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand * operand;
    }
    else if([@"/" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {

        if (operand)
        {
            operand = waitingOperand / operand;


      }
   }

}
-(double)performOperation:(NSString *) operation
{

    if ([operation isEqual:@"sqrt"])
    {
        operand = sqrt(operand);
    }
    else if([@"*+/-=" isEqual:operation])
    {
        [self performWaitingOperation];
        waitingOperation = operation;
        waitingOperand = operand;

 }
return operand;

}

@end
<code>
```

Comment: Maybe in `performWaitingOperation` you are not including the "=" operation at all.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the if([@"*+/-=" isEqual:operation]) catch, another catch is this:

```
if ([@"*" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand - operand;
    }
    else if ([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand * operand;
    }
```

Logic is wrong.

Next change the performWaitingOperation function to this,

```
-(double) performWaitingOperation{

    if ([@"+" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        return operand = waitingOperand + operand;
    }
    else if ([@"*" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        return operand = waitingOperand * operand;
    }
    else if ([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        return operand = waitingOperand - operand;
    }
    else if([@"/" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {

        if (operand)
        {
            return operand = waitingOperand / operand;


      }
   }else if ([@"=" isEqual:waitingOperation]){
        return operand;
     }

}
```

and change `[self performWaitingOperation]; to operand = [self performWaitingOperation];`

Good starter: [Calculator tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiA4AkmCezU)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

I think it is this line here. if([@"*+/-=" isEqual:operation]). Unless your string 'operation' is literally the string "*+/-=" then that will never evaluate to true. You probably want, instad, to compare against each of thos individually. eg if([@"*" isEqual:operation] || [@"+" isEqual:operation] ... etc

Comment: This was not the issue of the = sign but I give you credit for the catch of that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any issue refer the following [link](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall)
It gives you the the Calculator Brain project all together.

Comment: Thank you. I was watching the tutorials from 2010. This link take you to the ones from 2011. But I will go over those too.

Comment: Look around. This is the link for the 2010 session http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall